# Adding previously saved getImageData of canvas on top of other image

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to cover the whole canvas with an image while letting a transparent hole in it.

Basically I have a game with a player on it. I want to cover the whole game with an image except for the position of the player. This works fine when I consider a fill option with color but I want to do it with an image. Below is my (failing) code :

```
var img = new Image();

img.onload = function() {

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

  drawMap(); // draws my "hidden game"

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = visionRadial(game.p1.px, game.p1.py);
  ctx.rect(game.p1.px - 50, game.p1.py - 50, 100, 100);
  ctx.fill(); // this gives me a transparent circle around the position of the player.

  // Trying to save the image around my player
  var p1 = ctx.getImageData(game.p1.px - 50, game.p1.py - 50, 100, 100);

  // Image to cover the board game
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

  // Adding back the player position (transparent lens)
  ctx.putImageData(p1, game.p1.px - 50, game.p1.py - 50);

};

img.src = 'example.jpg';
```

But this does not work. It seems like when I'm saving the part of previous image in p1, the image does not display anymore...

What am I missing here ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Canvas, a drawable image

The functions`getImageData` and `putImageData` are just for manipulating pixels. Using pixel data to render is VERY slow as pixel data is not rendered by the  GPU,  does not do transparency, filters, composites, scaling, etc. Almost useless as a rendering source

Rather than store the image as pixel data create a second canvas, draw what you need on it and use it as an image with full hardware support and all the other stuff you can do with images.

### Example

Modifying your code to use a canvas to hold the overlay.

```
// creates a canvas, size w, h , and copies canvasToCopy onto it at x, y 
function createOverlay(canvasToCopy, x, y, w, h) {
    const overlay = document.createElement("canvas");
    overlay.width = w;
    overlay.height = h;
    const ctx = overlay.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(canvasToCopy, -x, -y);  // copies canvas to overlay
    return overlay;
}
var overlay; // to hold overlay image (a canvas)
var img = new Image();
img.src = "example.jpg";
img.onload = () => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  drawMap(); 
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = visionRadial(game.p1.px, game.p1.py);
  ctx.rect(game.p1.px - 50, game.p1.py - 50, 100, 100);
  ctx.fill(); 

  // copy current canvas content to overlay
  overlay = createOverlay(ctx.canvas, game.p1.px - 50, game.p1.py - 50, 100, 100);

  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

  // draw overlay over canvas content
  ctx.drawImage(overlay, game.p1.px - 50, game.p1.py - 50);

  img.onload = undefined; // never leave an onload (any unused event) set once done
                          // De-reference so resources closed over can be set free

};
```